# I am trying to take user inputs and add them together then comparing them to a variable

Tags: java

I made 4 classes. 
first class

```
public void bust(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your Bust Size: ");
        int bust_size1 = user_input.nextInt();

        int y = bust_size1;

        if (y>=33 & y<=34.5) {
            System.out.println("You are Small Bust" );
        } else if (y>=35 & y<37 ) {
            System.out.println("You are Medium Bust");
        } else if (y>=37 & y<=40.5) {
            System.out.println("You are Large Bust");
        } else {
            System.out.println("sorry you entered a incorrect number,");
        }
}
```

// all of the classes look similar
then my main class that takes these 3 classes together-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bust bustmain = new bust();
        hip hipmain = new hip();
        waist waistmain = new waist();

        bustmain.bust(args);
        waistmain.waist(args);
        hipmain.hip(args);
    }
```

What i am trying to achieve is this exactly: I want users to input their numbers for their bust size, waist, then hips. If they input a number such as 33, they will be in the small category, which i set the small category to a value such as 1. The values then will be added to determine what they will be.

Comment: Please structure your question so it's more clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to pass args to the functions

```
    bustmain.bust(args[0]);
    waistmain.waist(args[1]);
    hipmain.hip(args[2]);
```

and then

```
public void bust(int input) {

    int bust_size1 = input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need your bust() method to return something, or store the input as a field in the class itself that can be accessed by your main.